# How to create xml files using php

Tags: php

I am create a simple web-application in php.

when user save a data in form all data store in xml format.

So, Please give me the solution.

Comment: XML is just a structured text file. Why not try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you googling than also meet the answer but also check below code

');
            $node->addChild('content', $text);
            $xml = $node->asXML();
            file_put_contents('sample.xml', $xml);
        }
       $xml = simplexml_load_file('sample.xml');
        $text = htmlspecialchars($xml->content);
    ?>

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML data: Storing in XML, editing with CKEditor</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Our page editing form -->
        <form action="" method="post">
            <textarea name="editor1">
                <?php
                    // Echo our escaped HTML data into the textarea.
                    echo $text;
                ?>
            </textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

        <script>
            // Add CKEditor to textarea with name 'editor1'.
            CKEDITOR.replace( "editor1" );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

- This above code is one Example but you can use as your way
- If any problem with this answer please comment me...:)